# python access class method from class variable

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to access a class method from the class variable as follows:

```
class A():
    a = A.b()

    @classmethod
    def b():
        return 5


print A.a
```

but i get the error:

```
NameError: name 'A' is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `A` within `A`. You should, first of all, put all of your initialization in an `__init__` definition. And then use `self` to call upon itself.

```
class A():
    def __init__ (self):
        self.a = self.b()

    @classmethod
    def b(cls):
        return 5

print A().a
```

Comment: thanks, I'm familiar with the other approach, but I want to use the class variable for this case. How can I achieve that behavior while using class variable. Should I define the method outside of the class?